# Expresion regular de 0 a 10 digitos con excepcion de 9 digitos

Tags: angular, regex

que expresion regular me sirve para que un input permita la entrada de 0 a 8 digitos no permita 9 pero si permita 10 digitos.

Intento lo siguiente pero no funciona:

```html
<input (blur)="onBlurValidate($event)" type="number" class="form-control-white-select" style="border-radius: 0 0.8rem 0.8rem 0 !important"(keydown)="helper.onlyNumber($event); helper.maxLength($event, 10)" [(ngModel)]="clientStudyForm.comprador_documento"
(paste)="clientStudyForm.comprador_documento=helper.pasteOnlyNumber($event)"
name="comprador_documento" placeholder="Ingresar..."  pattern="/^(\d{0,8}|\d{10})$/g" required>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo? Podrías hacer una directiva, que permita valores nulos/vacíos (0 dígitos) y de 1 a 99999999 (8 dígitos) y valores desde 1000000000 hasta 9999999999 (10 dígitos). De este modo, si colocan 9 dígitos, queda validado.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. _Esta pregunta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._

Comment: Por qué dices que no funciona?

Answer (score 0):

El atributo [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) acepta un texto, sin los delimitadores `/` del regex. Y se usa en un input `type=text` o similares, pero no en `type=number`. Además, siempre está anclado a `^` y `$` por lo que no hace falta incluirlos.

Así quedaría:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    name="comprador_documento" 
    placeholder="Ingresar..."  
    pattern="\d{0,8}|\d{10}" 
    required
>
```

- Al haber únicamente 2 opciones, los paréntesis eran innecesarios.